# Python Writing a numpy array to a CSV File

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I'm trying to write a 2D numpy array to a CSV File
I tried this:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

w = csv.writer(open('main.csv','w'))

Nlayers=23
N=364
TempLake=np.zeros((N,Nlayers))

for i in xrange(N-1):
    TempLake[i+1]=TempLake[i]+100

w.writerow(TempLake)

outfile = open('main.csv', 'w')

writer = csv.writer(outfile)

ar=np.array(TempLake)

for row in TempLake:
    writer.writerow(row)
outfile.close()
```

Why some of the rows still have quotes? Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html), specifying a comma as the delimiter.