# Save tuple of numpy arrays to disk?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm getting a tuple of numpy arrays as `(keypoint, descriptor)` when I run the [`compute`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_extractors.html) function to extract them from an image.

Is there a way to pack this tuple together so that I can save them to a file, or write them into a CSV as a row?

Comment: Are they always one-dimensional or always two-dimensional?

Comment: You can save your tuple to a file straight away, e.g. with ``pickle``.

Comment: I believe they both  two dimensional

Comment: `np.savez` can save several arrays to a ZIP  archive.  `np.savetxt` writes a CSV like text file.  It just arranges its input into a 2d array, and then writes it (with a format string), one row per file line.  Nothing fancy.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Running Python 2.7.9

Comment: I just noticed that my suggested edit to add a `python-2.x` tag was rejected, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this:

- You can use Python [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), specifically [`writer` objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects):

  ```
  import csv
  writer = csv.writer(open("file.csv","w"))
  for row in array:
       writer.writerow(str(row))
  ```

  According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862471/python-writing-a-numpy-array-to-a-csv-file), there might be some formatting problems with this.
- As mentioned in the comments, you can use [`numpy.savetxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html). This is probably the best way:

  ```
  numpy.savetxt("file.csv",array,delimiter=",")
  ```
- You can also use the [`pickle` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html):

  ```
  import pickle
  pickle.dump(array,open("file","w"))
  ```

  As mentioned in the docs I linked above, `pickle.load()` should not be used to load untrusted data.

Comment: Pickle seems to be the easiest way of storing a tuple of numpy arrays. Thanks!

Comment: `csv.writer()` takes a **file object**, not a filename; `with open('file.csv', 'wb') as outf: writer = csv.writer(outf)`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I just noticed that when checking for differences in Python 2 vs. Python 3. I fixed it.

Comment: i don't think you mean to be using the `.csv` file suffix in the `pickle` dump.  also, shouldn't you be opening it in binary mode (i.e., `'wb'`)?

Comment: You're right about the first point (though the extension doesn't really matter, but `pickle.dump()` doesn't need a file opened in binary mode.

Comment: ah, ok, good to know.  i always use `'wb'`.  the extension doesn't _really_ matter, but at the same time it does matter, because a non-CSV file with a `.csv` suffix can cause a lot of confusion.

Comment: why not give it a pickle file suffix, like `.p` or `.pkl`?

Comment: I just noticed that I left an open parenthesis without a closing one up there, and that comment is too old to edit.)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `pickle`, I would recommend using [`cPickle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle):

```
import cPickle as pickle
pickle.dump(array, open('file.p', 'wb'))
```

Note that all of your calls remain the same as when you are using `pickle` -- only the `import` line changes.

`cPickle` is much faster than `pickle` and with large arrays can save you a lot of time.

That said, when you're dealing with `numpy` arrays, using `numpy`'s save functions -- e.g., `np.savetxt` -- is your best bet.